# TastyPie urls are not working

Tags: django, tastypie

I've been pulling my hair our on this one. After following the tutorial from the tastypie website I've setup tastypie in the following way. However whenever I go to any of the urls I'm getting a url does not found 404 error. Any help is much appreciated!

```
# EXAMPLE URL NOT WORKING: http://mylocalserver/api/bluebird/album/


# MODEL FILE #################################################################
# Django imports
from django.db import models
# Python imports
import datetime


class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today())
    school = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Picture(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey('Album')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    old_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    picture_location = models.ImageField(upload_to="BlueBird/Pictures/")
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

# API FILE #################################################################
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from models import Album
from models import Picture


class AlbumResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Album.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'album'


class PictureResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Picture.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'picture'

# URL FILE 
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

# TastyPie API
from tastypie.api import Api

# BlueBird imports
import BlueBird.views
from BlueBird.api import AlbumResource
from BlueBird.api import PictureResource

# BlueBird API
bluebird_api = Api(api_name='bluebird')
bluebird_api.register(AlbumResource())
bluebird_api.register(PictureResource())
#album_resource = AlbumResource()
#picture_resource = PictureResource()

# for development only - remove in production server and reconfigure settings file if   needed
#from django.conf import settings
#from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
                       url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
                       url(r'^api/$', include(bluebird_api.urls)),
                       #url(r'^api/$', include(album_resource.urls)),
                       )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is good - but you have an extra "$" sign on the url registration on the api. use:

```
url(r'^api/', include(bluebird_api.urls)),
```

Instead of:

```
url(r'^api/$', include(bluebird_api.urls)),
```

Then, the url '/api/bluebird/album/' works.